# Missing Controller error for baked plugin in CakePHP 3.1

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1

I did a fresh installation of CakePHP 3.1. Then I baked a plugin. Then I baked a plugin controller.

Done as per the example in the documentation:
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#creating-your-own-plugins

But when I go to /cake-cms/cake-cms I get a Missing Controller error.

```
Error: Create the class CakeCmsController below in file: src\Controller\CakeCmsController.php
```

The baked code all looks fine to me. The baked plugin routes.php is being executed (I tested with exit;). The baked controller exists in:
/plugins/CakeCms/src/Controller/CakeCmsController.php but CakePHP is not looking there.

The example in the documentation says it should just work.

Comment: Where in the docs does it say that this would work?

Comment: http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#creating-a-plugin-using-bake
and
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/plugins.html#plugin-controllers
"If you want to access what we’ve got going thus far, visit /contact-manager/contacts"

Comment: Ok, but you can see that this URL is a little different, right? `contact-manager` is the plugin, and `contacts` is the controller. Your URL contains just one of those two.

Comment: That's a good point, however I get the same error on /cake-cms/cake-cms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, it looks like my problem was that my plugin had the same name as my project (cakecms). When I make a plugin with a different name then it works.